# Use toggle button to update stored value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to javascript and trying to adjust an existing example as [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dominijk/L1v8mogk/9/). On toggling of the button the two stored variables should be updated with new value or old value if turning toggle off.

This is what I've tried so far;

```js
//before toggling variables are stored as
var CountPropertySource = "current_rating";
var AreaPropertySource = "current_rating";

//After toggling variable should be stored as 
var CountPropertySource = "potential_rating";
var AreaPropertySource = "potential_rating"; 

$(function(){
    $("#tglSendValue").click(function(e){
        $("#sendvalue").val($("#sendvalue").val() == "current"? CountPropertySource='potential' : CountPropertySource='current' );
        alert(CountPropertySource);
    });
});
```

Comment: You can't set a value that way. This `statement ? true : false` does not do that. I would advise using an IF statement.

Answer (score 1):

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/kafxwd70/

Consider using an `if` statement as it can execute more code.

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var CountPropertySource = "current_rating";
  var AreaPropertySource = "current_rating";
  $("#tglSendValue").click(function(e) {
    if ($("#sendvalue").val() == "current") {
      $("#sendvalue").val("potential");
      CountPropertySource = "potential_rating";
    } else {
      $("#sendvalue").val("current");
      CountPropertySource = "current_rating";
    }
    alert(CountPropertySource);
  });
});
```

> The `if` statement executes a statement if a specified condition is truthy. If the condition is falsy, another statement can be executed.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else

> The conditional (ternary) operator is the only JavaScript operator that takes three operands. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the `if` statement.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 0):

you can try to do something like this:

```
var baseValue = 'current_rating';
var modifiedValue = 'potential_rating';

var CountPropertySource = baseValue;
var AreaPropertySource  = baseValue;

$(function(){
    $("#tglSendValue").click(function(e){
      if ($("#sendvalue").val() == 'current') {
        $("#sendvalue").val('potential');
        CountPropertySource = modifiedValue;
      } else {
        $("#sendvalue").val('current');
        CountPropertySource = baseValue;
      }
      alert(CountPropertySource);
    });
});
```

Put it in a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nb0jwt4a/1/) as well. Hopefully that helps to shed a bit of light!

Comment: We posted at the same time. Ugh.

Comment: why have you split out the baseValue like that, does it do something different?

Comment: In your example, no. You do not get any benefits from it like this, but in a more complex project, the benefit of having a variable declaration paragraph or segment can lead to clarity of code and better legibility.